# Column '[Student Name]' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

i tried to solve the issue but could not solve same columns name but it's not working. How to solve it?

```
private void GetData()
{
    try
    {
        dt.Columns.Clear();
        dt.Rows.Clear();

        char[] alignment = new char[22];
        int[] width = new int[22];
        dt.Columns.Add("S.No", typeof(int)); alignment[0] = 'C'; width[0] = 20;
        dt.Columns.Add("Ad.No", typeof(int)); alignment[1] = 'C'; width[1] = 20;
        dt.Columns.Add("Gr No", typeof(string)); alignment[2] = 'L'; width[2] = 60;
        //dt.Columns.Add("Father Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Ad. Date", typeof(string)); alignment[3] = 'L'; width[3] = 30;
        dt.Columns.Add("[Student Name]", typeof(string)); alignment[4] = 'C'; width[0] = 20;
        dt.Columns.Add("Father Name", typeof(string)); alignment[5] = 'C'; width[0] = 20;

        string query = "";
        if (radioButtonClass.Checked)
        {
            query = " select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  Class,StudentName) AS [S.No], AdmissionNo as [Ad.No], EnrollmentNo as [Gr No],convert(varchar,AdmissionDate,103)as [Ad.Date],StudentName as [Student Name],FatherName as [Father Name],  " +
                   " from vu_StdAdmissionFeeInfo " +
                   " where AdmissionDate >='" + dtpform.Value + "' and AdmissionDate<='" + dtpTo.Value + "'" +
                   "" + (cmbClass.Text.Equals("--Select--") ? "" : " and Class='" + cmbClass.Text + "'   ") +
                   "" + (cmbsection.Text.Equals("--Select--") ? "" : " and Section='" + cmbsection.Text + "'   ") +
                   " order by Class,StudentName";
                        }
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2 = utility.Get(query);
        //  dt2.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt2.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["S.NO"] = item["S.NO"];
            dr["Ad.No"] = item["Ad.No"];
            dr["Gr No"] = item["Gr No"];
            dr["Ad. Date"] = item["Ad. Date"];
            dr["[Student Name]"] = item["[Student Name]"];
            dr["Father Name"] = item["Father Name"];

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dt2.Rows.Clear();
       // dt.Rows.Clear();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dgvReport.DataSource = null;
            dgvReport.DataSource = dt;          
        }
        else
        {
            dgvReport.DataSource = null;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Column names should not contain `space`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: When you do `As [Student Name]` in SQL you are naming the return column `Student Name` without the brackets.  The brackets are just there to tell SQL that the space is part of the name.

Comment: Hemal [Ad. Date] have aslo space

Comment: Please, avoid rollback on useful edit.

Comment: @RATHORE I think Hemal is just making a recommendation because having spaces in names in SQL can be problematic.

Answer (score 3):

Remove Brackets of **[Student Name]** in below code:

```
                foreach (DataRow item in dt2.Rows)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["S.NO"] = item["S.NO"];
                    dr["Ad.No"] = item["Ad.No"];
                    dr["Gr No"] = item["Gr No"];
                    dr["Ad. Date"] = item["Ad. Date"];
                    dr["[Student Name]"] = item["[Student Name]"];
                    dr["Father Name"] = item["Father Name"];

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
```

Or this Code :

```
dt.Columns.Add("[Student Name]", typeof(string)); alignment[4] = 'C'; width[0] = 20;
```

Or

> Remove the Spaces of your Columns

Comment: put breakpoint in your code then see where the exception raises.

Comment: then remove the Spaces of your column title.